# PHP not loading sqlsrv extension

Tags: php

I have problems for PHP to use sqlserver, I download the controllers to use php and sql since I am trying to connect laravel to my database, download two drivers for a computer for x64 but I get the following error:PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv_82_ts_x64.dll' (tried: ext\pdo_sqlsrv_82_ts_x64.dll (No se puede encontrar el m├│dulo especificado), ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_82_ts_x64.dll.dll (No se puede encontrar el m├│dulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try adding `php_`. Use `php_sqlsrv_82_ts_x64.dll` instead of `sqlsrv_82_ts_x64.dll`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including the prefix `php_` worked for me

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_82_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_82_ts_x64.dll
```